# substitute for pneumatic oil

Tags: tools

Can I use Appliance oil as a substitute for pneumatic oil in my nail guns? I've heard different opinions and would like to know what the difference in the two oils are. Of all the different oils I have on hand,  I think it might be the best substitution to finish a job when getting pneumatic oil isn't an option for me right now. Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you choose the appliance oil because it said it was safe for o-rings?

Comment: A four ounce bottle of pnuematic oil costs $3, and the instructions say to use a drop per day. Is it really worth the time to research an alternative? There are [600 drops in an ounce](http://www.traditionaloven.com/culinary-arts/volume/convert-liquid-ounce-fl-oz-us-to-drop.html), so one bottle should last about 7 years per tool

Answer (score 1):

Any oil is better than no oil.  We use 3 in 1 oil in our shop daily.  Our grinders hold up very well and are used all day long.